# Display non-editable text at end of EditText in android

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

[image]

I want to display text at the end of EditText as shown in the image above for URLName.How could I acheive this ?The text cannot be edited.I am using this editText inside `TextInputLayout` from the design library. thanks in advance

Comment: @TimCastelijns please read the question carefully. its completely different question

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma how do you figure?

Comment: author needs an EditText on which the right side field is completed by a static text which can't changed by user. m i ryt ?  @bearded

Comment: yes. thats what I wanted

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562959/how-to-set-the-cursor-to-the-right-edittext

Answer (score 3):

- Create a `LinearLayout`. An example of a row inside this layout would be a title (i.e. URL name) or a text entry field.
- Set the background of the `LinearLayout` for the current row to a custom drawable to create a thin red line. Follow the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458694/android-background-with-a-thin-line) post for ideas.
- For the URL entry field mentioned in your question, create a `TextView` and an `EditText` inside another `LinearLayout` inside the current row.

The `TextView` will contain ".sitename.com". Set it to `wrap_content` and give it a `weight` of `0`. For your `EditText`, set its `width` to `0dp` and its `weight` to `1`. It should now fill all remaining space.  Set the `background` to `@null` for both.

Comment: I want to make use of latest TextInputLayout for this EditText.

Comment: This is normal method right ? Apart from the above solution is there a way I could achieve this ?

Comment: @beardedbeast I've never used it, but isn't `TextInputLayout` interchangeable with `EditText`?

Comment: @beardedbeast You could also, possibly, achieve it with `TextWatcher`, but given that you want one element off to the right and another to the left, this is a more straightforward and robust approach, as near as I can tell.

Comment: no its just a layout inside which we give the editText.

Comment: @beardedbeast Sure, so you should be able to just apply anything said above for `EditText` to your `TextInputLayout` wrapper.

Comment: but the problem here is animation for hint is not working now

Comment: @beardedbeast Just because it's inside a `LinearLayout`? This is a common situation, so I'm surprised. Under what conditions does the label animate correctly? You could swap the `LinearLayout` on that row for a `RelativeLayout`, for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93998/discussion-between-ppartisan-and-bearded-beast).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
<RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/youeeditid"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="HintText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's little bit tricky but it's works for me.

**BUT**

If you want to set only EditText then you can do below :

> 1) Set Gravity of EditText to "Right" and Ellipsize to "End" .
>
> 2) Now In onCreate() method write onclicklistener of EditText and set
>   Gravity as "Left".
>
> 3) Or you can also set programatically on OnKeyListener , where check
>   if lenght of edittext is equal to Zero set  EditText's gravity as
>   Left.

Reference : [Setting cursor to the right on an EditText with HINT Gravity to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694800/setting-cursor-to-the-right-on-an-edittext-with-hint-gravity-to-center)

Comment: How could I implement this inside TextInputLayout ? any idea ?

Comment: If the edittext grows then it will overlap the textview.