# Android - EditText set prefix always visible

Tags: android

I made a custom EditText with the possibility to add a prefix, this work well but I want my prefix to stay visible even if the size of the text typed is too large.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRakZ.png) you can see my EditText with a prefix.
And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsdX6.png) you can see the problem I am facing.

Here's my Edittext class:

```
public class MyEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
{
    private String mPrefix;
    private Rect mPrefixRect = new Rect();

    public void setPrefix(final String prefix)
    {
        mPrefix = prefix;
    }

    public MyEditText(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mPrefix = "";
    }

    public MyEditText(final Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet)
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.MyEditText, 0, 0);
        mPrefix = a.getString(R.styleable.MyEditText_prefix);
        if (mPrefix == null)
            mPrefix = "";
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        getPaint().getTextBounds(mPrefix, 0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefixRect);
        if (!mPrefix.matches(""))
            mPrefixRect.right += getPaint().measureText("  "); // add some offset
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompoundPaddingLeft()
    {
        return super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + mPrefixRect.width();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There is my R.styleable.MyEditText as requested:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyEditText">
        <attr name="prefix" format="string" />
        <attr name="parentLayout" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And there is my XML file where I am using MyEditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="thurluth.popups.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <MyEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:prefix="Login :"
        app:parentLayout="@id/main_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**SOLUTION**

For those who have the same problem that I jad, there is the solution:

You have to override the onDraw function in your custom EditText

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        float prefixPosX = 10;  //I added some offset at the left the prefix
        if (paint.measureText(getText().toString()) > getWidth() - (paint.measureText(mPrefix + "  ")) - 10)
            prefixPosX = paint.measureText(getText().toString() + offset) - (getWidth() - (paint.measureText(mPrefix + "  ")));
        canvas.drawText(mPrefix, prefixPosX, getBaseline(), paint);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use textview for that purpose?

Comment: Because I have more method inside I just put the one useful for the prefix ^^

Comment: I second @R.R.M - this will be far simpler, and more robust, if you just place `Login` inside its own `TextView` to the left of your `EditText`

Comment: I m confused with your sentence @PPartisan. Which one is more simpler? Mine or Ray Kytto's?

Comment: Show  R.styleable.MyEditText file.

Comment: @R.R.M Yours. Rather than attempting to define a prefix inside the `EditText` dynamically, it is simpler to just use a `TextView` for the prefix and a separate `EditText`. It's similar to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475533/display-non-editable-text-at-end-of-edittext-in-android/33475848#33475848

Comment: Yeah. Exactly!!!!!!!

Comment: I edited my post @Ankita

Comment: @PPartisan I understand what you mean but I'd really like to keep it like this

Comment: Post your XML. Where you are using MyEditText.

Comment: @Ankita I edited again my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is your own View, you can override the onDraw method.
The passed Canvas contains a method called `drawText`. Set it's position, create the needed `Paint` - object to make it cool fine and you're good to go :-)

Comment: I already tried to do `canvas.drawText(mPrefix, 0, getBaseline(), paint)` but it didn't work :/

Comment: I just had an idea,I'll try it and tell you if it works

Comment: I tired what I wanted to try and it works thanks a lot, I'll put the solution in my post ;)